# Select where image dimensions (hxw) above or equal to

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table of photos and store their dimensions in a single varchar field, ie. "1024x768". Is there way to select photos above or equal to the given dimensions without having to modify the table to store 'height' and 'width' separately?

Thanks

Comment: Are they _consistently always_ stored in the exact same format `WxH` with the `x` and no spaces between? It can be done but will be slow to query. The _real_ solution is to fix the table to store them separately.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to select an image with width >= 1024 and height >= 768?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(dimensions, 1, LOCATE("x", dimensions)-1) as NUMBER) > @height
AND CAST(SUBSTR(dimensions, LOCATE("x", dimensions)+1)) as NUMBER) > @width
```